# array manipulation

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

So i'm trying to avoid using vectors to do this, i know it would make it easier, but i'm trying to better my understanding of pointers and arrays. So is there a way to expand and shift an array without using the vectors? Here is what i have so far:

```
int *expand(int *&arr, int size)
{
    int *newArray;

    size = size * 2; 

    newArray = new int[size * 2];
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        newArray[index] = arr[index];
    return newArray;

}
```

Comment: Hi, you need to indent all code with 4 spaces, so that it will show up properly in the question :)

Comment: I don't see any vectors in there??

Comment: You are allocating **4** times the size, is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't changing the value of `arr` inside the function, there's no need to pass the address by reference.  If you did mean to change the value, you need to add a new line of code before the return newArray:

```
arr = newArray;
```

If the typical calling pattern is

```
arr = expand(arr, arr_size);
```

then you'll also need to watch out for options that ignore [aliasing](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2006-08/msg00236.html).  And you'll have to make assumptions within `expand` that size is always doubled, and keep track of that yourself outside of it.

Also, your code has a terrible bug.  size is doubled, and then used as the array limit for the source array.   Then it leaks the memory that was previously allocated for `arr`. This is a good reason why people use `std::vector`. :-)  Most of the bugs are out of that library, by now.

```
void expand_in_place(int *&arr, int& size)
{
    const new_size = size * 2;
    int *new_array = new int[new_size];

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        new_array[index] = arr[index];

    delete[] arr;
    arr = newArray;
    size = new_size;
}
```

If you were using `malloc` and `free` instead of `new []` and `delete []`, you could use `realloc`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do what you want would be the standard library function realloc.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/

```
int* new_array = (int*) realloc (old_array, new_size * sizeof(int));
```

Note the ***sizeof(int)**. That's important :)
*realloc* makes sure the contents of *old_array* can be found in *new_array*(it's either the same pointer, or the contents are copied). See the link for details.

Comment: Note, then, that the `realloc`'d memory *cannot* be acquired by `new`, and cannot be free'd with `delete`. This is very C-ish, doesn't call constructors, etc.

Comment: Precisely. If you wanted it to be C++-ish, you would use vectors :)

Comment: @x10: Well not really, `vector` *does* need to be implemented somehow, and it doesn't use `realloc`.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean. Well, he *could* allocate new memory, std::copy the contents, deallocate the old memory, set the pointer reference to the new value and return it. But a standard library call is easier :)

Comment: @x10: But like I said, it's not an equal choice; this is now dependent on C allocation functions instead of C++ allocation expressions.

Answer (score 3):

In c++, try to avoid raw pointers. But since this is an exercise, this is a c++ way :

```
int *expand(int *&arr, int size)
{
    int *newArray = new int[2*size];

    std::copy( &arr[0],&arr[size], &newArray[0] );
    // delete [] arr; // need to delete?

    return newArray;
}
```

---

To do in place :

```
void expand(int *&arr, int size)
{
    int *newArray = new int[2*size];

    std::copy( &arr[0],&arr[size], &newArray[0] );
    delete [] arr;

    arr = newArray;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the int*& arr should just be an int* arr in this case?

Comment: @x10 See edit how to do it in place. No need to return anything

Answer (score 1):

To do it manually, you need to copy the old data with the size of the original array, right now you're walking off the end of the original array.

Try this:

```
int *expand(int *&arr, int size)
{
    int *newArray;

    newArray = new int[size * 2];
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        newArray[index] = arr[index];
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You're allocating twice as much memory as you need.
- You're not deleting the old array.
- You're not assigning the new pointer to `arr` - passing it as reference indicates that's what you intended - or that you intended to `delete[]` arr and assign 0 to it.

Comment: So what if i wanted to initialized the new space in the array with elements, for example if i print out the new array the new spaces in the array have numbers in them?

Comment: @Smar: Keep the loop initializing it

Answer (score 1):

See this **[link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/11111/)** for a method that uses **memcpy** instead of looping through individual items.

```
int *expand(int *&arr, int size)
{
    size_t newSize = size * 2;
    int* newArr = new int[newSize];

    memcpy( newArr, arr, size * sizeof(int) );

    size = newSize;
    delete [] arr;
    arr = newArr;
}
```

Comment: memcpy also doesn't care about constructor/destructors

Comment: he's got an array of integers, does that matter?

Comment: In that case - no. Generally speaking - it matters